# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection VB.net Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, gridview

I have a gridview in Visual Studio, one of the collumns displays small icon logo's based on what file type has been inserted into that row, 
I have created some code which I believe should open up the attatched file once the icon has been clicked on.

When i run the code, I get this error:

*Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter(name) : index().
Line 530: ImgBtn.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:window.open('DisplayPM.aspx?ServiceID=" + Service_History.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Value.ToString + "');")*

I cannot get around this problem.

**This is my code in the ASPX for the Gridview:**

```
                                 <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="PdfExtention2" runat="server" ImageUrl="../icons/pdf.gif" Visible="false"/>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="WordExtention2" runat="server" ImageUrl="../icons/actn103.gif" Visible="false"/>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ExcelExtention2" runat="server" ImageUrl="../icons/actn102.gif" Visible="false"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle Width="25%" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

**This is my code in VB  in the Gridview RowDataBound:**

```
        Dim pdfExtention2, wordExtention2, excelExtention2 As ImageButton

        pdfExtention2 = e.Row.FindControl("PdfExtention2")
        wordExtention2 = e.Row.FindControl("WordExtention2")
        excelExtention2 = e.Row.FindControl("ExcelExtention2")

        If e.Row.DataItem("Extention").ToString = "application/pdf" Then
            pdfExtention2.Visible = True
        ElseIf e.Row.DataItem("Extention").ToString = "application/msword" Then
            wordExtention2.Visible = True
        ElseIf e.Row.DataItem("Extention").ToString = "application/vnd.ms-excel" Then
            excelExtention2.Visible = True
        End If

        '-----------------------------------------------------------------

        Dim ImgBtn As New ImageButton
        ImgBtn = e.Row.FindControl("PdfExtention2")
        ImgBtn.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:window.open('DisplayPM.aspx?ServiceID=" + Service_History.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Value.ToString + "');")

        Dim ImgBtn2 As New ImageButton
        ImgBtn2 = e.Row.FindControl("WordExtention2")
        ImgBtn2.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:window.open('DisplayPM.aspx?ServiceID=" + Service_History.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Value.ToString + "');")

        Dim ImgBtn3 As New ImageButton
        ImgBtn3 = e.Row.FindControl("ExcelExtention2")
        ImgBtn3.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:window.open('DisplayPM.aspx?ServiceID=" + Service_History.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Value.ToString + "');")
```

I was hoping I could get some assistance with where i'm going wrong.
Thankyou in advance

Comment: Did you set the DataKeys property in your markup or in code before binding?

Comment: I've just implemented the Data Key in my markup and it's working now! Cheers. @Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem!

I needed to put:

```
DataKeyNames="ServiceID,ID"
```

in the markup for the gridview and now it works fine.

I will make this the solved answer after 2 days.